# How to draw this Form as a Shape(XML-Drawable) in Android Studio

Tags: xml, shapes, drawable, android-drawable

How can i draw or create this navigation background as a shape in Android Studio.
To draw a rectangle is not the problem. Instead of this i need an idea for drawing the inner oval (transparent).

[image: Shape with transparent oval inside]

I tryed again and again but didn't get success on drawing the transparent oval form in the middle of rectangle.